# How to round numbers used in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rounding, dplyr

First is the sample data and manipulations and then the code that im using to create the horizontal bar chart. Everything works fine except that I can't figure out how to round the numbers used in the data labels. First, how does round the number in the data label. I used the following "scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma, accuracy=1)" and appended it to what I have but got errors due to the comma next to accuracy. Also, tried a mutate (and round command) in the data frame but that was unsuccessful. Any ideas on how best to accomplish this?

```
    A<- c(150.333,125.888,0,-300.5555,-350.444,-370.99999)
    Series<- c("Construction","Manufacturing","Information","Health_Care","Education","Government")

    testdf <- data.frame(A,Series)

    ggplot(data = testdf, aes(y = A, x = reorder(Series, A))) +
    geom_col(color = "blue") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 0.5)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = A, hjust = ifelse(A > 0, 0, 1), y = A + ifelse(A > 0, 10, -10))) +
    labs(x = NULL) +
    ggtitle("Job Growth") +
    theme(
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
     )
```

tried this as well. No errors but the plot does not change.

```
jobgrowth<- ggplot(data = testdf, aes(y = A, x = reorder(Series, A))) +
geom_col(color = "blue") +
coord_flip() +
scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma(A, accuracy=1),expand = 
expansion(mult = 0.5)) +
geom_text(aes(label = A, hjust = ifelse(A > 0, 0, 1), y = A + ifelse(A > 0, 
10, -10))) +
labs(x = NULL) +
ggtitle("Job Growth") +
theme(
  plot.title.position = "plot",
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
)
```

Comment: Try with `label = scales::comma(A, accuracy=1)` inside geom_text.

Comment: @stefan, edited the question. did what you proposed and the chart does not change.

Answer (score 0):

As with all newcomers to a concept or software package, you go down rabbit holes. This does not work so you try this and try that. Mostly deviating further and further from the core concept issue as time goes on. Found the answer at (https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-add-labels-over-each-bar-in-barplot-in-r/). The issue is not the scale_y_continuous but the geom_text item. Seems like a duh moment but after a while, I noticed that the scale on the bottom was changing but not the data labels therefore it had to be something else.

```
 jobgrowth<- ggplot(data = testdf, aes(y = A, x = reorder(Series, A))) +
geom_col(color = "blue") +
coord_flip() +
scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma() ,expand = expansion(mult = 0.5)) +
geom_text(aes(label = round(A,0), hjust = ifelse(A > 0, 0, 1), y = A + ifelse(A > 0, 
10, -10))) +
labs(x = NULL) +
ggtitle("Job Growth") +
theme(
  plot.title.position = "plot",
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
)
```

Comment: Another option is to use `format`, for example: `label = format(A, digits=4, big.mark   = ",")`

Comment: @Dave2e, tried that and it works as well. Thanks for your input